# Custom Keras LSTM layer, In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: [Op:MatMul]

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to implement a custom LSTM keras layer in colab. The purpose of the layer is to pass the previous hidden_state_i and carry_state_i as the hidden_state_i+1 and carry_state_i+1 if the whole input tensor values are zero, otherwise do the calculations.
The implemented layer :

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)


@tf.function
def check_nonzero(inp):
  res = tf.math.count_nonzero(inp).numpy()
  return res

@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class mSIMPLELSTM(Layer):

     def __init__(self,units, **kwargs):
         self.units = units
         #self.state_size = [units, units]
         super(mSIMPLELSTM, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     
     def build(self, input_shape):
         self.w_xi = self.add_weight(name='w_xi',
                                    shape=(input_shape[0], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_xf = self.add_weight(name='w_xf',
                                    shape=(input_shape[0], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_xo = self.add_weight(name='w_xo',
                                    shape=(input_shape[0], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_xc = self.add_weight(name='w_xc',
                                    shape=(input_shape[0], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_hi = self.add_weight(name='w_hi',
                                    shape=(input_shape[0], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_hf = self.add_weight(name='w_hf',
                                    shape=(input_shape[0], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_ho = self.add_weight(name='w_ho',
                                    shape=(input_shape[0], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_hc = self.add_weight(name='w_hc',
                                    shape=(input_shape[0], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.b_i = self.add_weight(name='b_i',
                                    shape=(1, self.units), initializer='zeros')
         self.b_f = self.add_weight(name='b_f',
                                    shape=(1, self.units), initializer='zeros')
         self.b_o = self.add_weight(name='b_o',
                                    shape=(1, self.units), initializer='zeros')
         self.b_c = self.add_weight(name='b_c',
                                    shape=(1, self.units), initializer='zeros')
         self.built = True
     @tf.function()
     def Mcell(self, inputs, states):
        x = inputs
        h, c = states
        q=1
        if check_nonzero(inputs)> 0:
          c_n = c
          i = K.sigmoid(K.dot(x, self.w_xi) + K.dot(h, self.w_hi) + self.b_i)
          f = K.sigmoid(K.dot(x, self.w_xf) + K.dot(h, self.w_hf) + self.b_f)
          o = K.sigmoid(K.dot(x, self.w_xo) + K.dot(h, self.w_ho) + self.b_o)
          c_in = K.tanh(K.dot(x, self.w_xc) + K.dot(h, self.w_hc) + self.b_c)
          c_n = f * c + i * c_in
          h_n = o * K.tanh(c_n)
        else:
          c_n = c
          h_n = h
        
        return h_n, [h_n, c_n]
     @tf.function
     def call(self, inputs):
        print( "inputs.shape")
        print( inputs.shape)
        initial_states = [
            K.zeros((K.shape(inputs)[0], self.units)),
            K.zeros((K.shape(inputs)[0], self.units))
        ]
        print( "initial_states.shape")
        print(initial_states[0].shape)
        outputs = K.rnn(self.Mcell, inputs, initial_states)
        #o1,o2=self.Mcell(inputs,states)
        return outputs

     
     def get_config(self):
      config = {
      'units': self.units
      }
      base_config = super(mSIMPLELSTM, self).get_config()
      return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

     @classmethod
     def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)
     
     def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0] , self.units)
```

I call the model like :

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense , RNN
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

visible = Input(shape=(1,57600), sparse=True)
layer1 = mSIMPLELSTM(240, dynamic = True)(visible)
layer2 = Dropout(0.5)(layer1)
hidden = Dense(2,activation='softmax', input_shape=(None,240))(layer2)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=layer2)
opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt , metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(final_train, final_train_label, epochs=10, batch_size=240,verbose=2)
model.save('drive/My Drive/modelMLSTM_1_testing.h5' ,save_format="tf")
print(model.summary())
```

the `final_train.shape`  is  `(3875, 1, 57600)` and the `final_train_label.shape`  is  `(3875, 2)`  but the `fit()` function raises this error :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py:3704: UserWarning: Even though the `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly` option is set, this option does not apply to tf.data functions. To force eager execution of tf.data functions, please use `tf.data.experimental.enable.debug_mode()`.
  "Even though the `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly` "
Epoch 1/10
inputs.shape
(240, 1, 57600)
initial_states.shape
(240, 240)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e135325db3f6> in <module>()
     14 opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
     15 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt , metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 16 model.fit(final_train, final_train_label, epochs=10, batch_size=240,verbose=2)
     17 model.save('drive/My Drive/modelMLSTM_1_testing.h5' ,save_format="tf")
     18 print(model.summary())

27 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_function(iterator)
    853       def train_function(iterator):
    854         """Runs a training execution with one step."""
--> 855         return step_function(self, iterator)
    856 
    857     else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in step_function(model, iterator)
    843 
    844       data = next(iterator)
--> 845       outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    846       outputs = reduce_per_replica(
    847           outputs, self.distribute_strategy, reduction='first')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in run(***failed resolving arguments***)
   1283       fn = autograph.tf_convert(
   1284           fn, autograph_ctx.control_status_ctx(), convert_by_default=False)
-> 1285       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1286 
   1287   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   2831       kwargs = {}
   2832     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 2833       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   2834 
   2835   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   3606   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):
   3607     with ReplicaContext(self._container_strategy(), replica_id_in_sync_group=0):
-> 3608       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   3609 
   3610   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations, options):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    595   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    596     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.UNSPECIFIED):
--> 597       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    598 
    599   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in run_step(data)
    836 
    837       def run_step(data):
--> 838         outputs = model.train_step(data)
    839         # Ensure counter is updated only if `train_step` succeeds.
    840         with ops.control_dependencies(_minimum_control_deps(outputs)):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_step(self, data)
    793     # Run forward pass.
    794     with backprop.GradientTape() as tape:
--> 795       y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    796       loss = self.compiled_loss(
    797           y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1028         with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
   1029             self._compute_dtype_object):
-> 1030           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
   1031 
   1032         if self._activity_regularizer:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    419     """
    420     return self._run_internal_graph(
--> 421         inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    422 
    423   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
    554 
    555         args, kwargs = node.map_arguments(tensor_dict)
--> 556         outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    557 
    558         # Update tensor_dict.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1028         with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
   1029             self._compute_dtype_object):
-> 1030           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
   1031 
   1032         if self._activity_regularizer:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    864     if self._run_functions_eagerly:
    865       with trace.Trace(self._name, tf_function_call="eager"):
--> 866         return self._python_function(*args, **kwds)
    867 
    868     # Only count the statistics the fitst time, before initialization took

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in bound_method_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   3964       if tf_inspect.ismethod(wrapped_fn):
   3965         wrapped_fn = six.get_unbound_function(wrapped_fn)
-> 3966       return wrapped_fn(weak_instance(), *args, **kwargs)
   3967 
   3968     # If __wrapped__ was replaced, then it is always an unbound function.

<ipython-input-6-8aa4162c05cf> in call(self, inputs)
     76         print( "initial_states.shape")
     77         print(initial_states[0].shape)
---> 78         outputs = K.rnn(self.Mcell, inputs, initial_states)
     79         #o1,o2=self.Mcell(inputs,states)
     80         return outputs

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in rnn(step_function, inputs, initial_states, go_backwards, mask, constants, unroll, input_length, time_major, zero_output_for_mask)
   4376     # the value is discarded.
   4377     output_time_zero, _ = step_function(
-> 4378         input_time_zero, tuple(initial_states) + tuple(constants))
   4379     output_ta = tuple(
   4380         tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    864     if self._run_functions_eagerly:
    865       with trace.Trace(self._name, tf_function_call="eager"):
--> 866         return self._python_function(*args, **kwds)
    867 
    868     # Only count the statistics the fitst time, before initialization took

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in bound_method_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   3964       if tf_inspect.ismethod(wrapped_fn):
   3965         wrapped_fn = six.get_unbound_function(wrapped_fn)
-> 3966       return wrapped_fn(weak_instance(), *args, **kwargs)
   3967 
   3968     # If __wrapped__ was replaced, then it is always an unbound function.

<ipython-input-6-8aa4162c05cf> in Mcell(self, inputs, states)
     55         if check_nonzero(inputs)> 0:
     56           c_n = c
---> 57           i = K.sigmoid(K.dot(x, self.w_xi) + K.dot(h, self.w_hi) + self.b_i)
     58           f = K.sigmoid(K.dot(x, self.w_xf) + K.dot(h, self.w_hf) + self.b_f)
     59           o = K.sigmoid(K.dot(x, self.w_xo) + K.dot(h, self.w_ho) + self.b_o)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in dot(x, y)
   2006     out = sparse_ops.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(x, y)
   2007   else:
-> 2008     out = math_ops.matmul(x, y)
   2009   return out
   2010 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in matmul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, adjoint_a, adjoint_b, a_is_sparse, b_is_sparse, name)
   3488     else:
   3489       return gen_math_ops.mat_mul(
-> 3490           a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
   3491 
   3492 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in mat_mul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, name)
   5698       return _result
   5699     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 5700       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   5701     except _core._FallbackException:
   5702       pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6895   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6896   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6897   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6898   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6899 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: 57600 vs. 240: [240,57600] [240,240] 0 0 [Op:MatMul]
```

I am new in Keras and LSTMs, but when I define the code as an LSTM cell it works nice and doesn't raise this error. unfortunately, I need to write a layer because I need to save and load the model as a  `custom_objects`. I already tried to change the `initial_states` to :

```
initial_states = [
            K.zeros((K.shape(inputs)[-1], self.units)),
            K.zeros((K.shape(inputs)[-1], self.units))
        ]
```

and changed the layer `build()` function to :

```
    def build(self, input_shape):
         self.w_xi = self.add_weight(name='w_xi',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_xf = self.add_weight(name='w_xf',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_xo = self.add_weight(name='w_xo',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_xc = self.add_weight(name='w_xc',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_hi = self.add_weight(name='w_hi',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_hf = self.add_weight(name='w_hf',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_ho = self.add_weight(name='w_ho',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.w_hc = self.add_weight(name='w_hc',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer='uniform')
         self.b_i = self.add_weight(name='b_i',
                                    shape=(1, self.units), initializer='zeros')
         self.b_f = self.add_weight(name='b_f',
                                    shape=(1, self.units), initializer='zeros')
         self.b_o = self.add_weight(name='b_o',
                                    shape=(1, self.units), initializer='zeros')
         self.b_c = self.add_weight(name='b_c',
                                    shape=(1, self.units), initializer='zeros')
         self.built = True
```

but again raises the same error. Does anyone know where I'm doing it wrong? :

```
In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: 240 vs. 57600: [57600,240] [57600,240] 0 0 [Op:MatMul]
```

Comment: excuse me did you solve it ?

Comment: @user5520049 No! but I found it happens only in the functional models and it's related to the input shape. if you try to change the shape of the LSTM input, maybe the error disappears.